# flash cs5 always exporting old version

Tags: flash-cs5

I'm making simple file with images, animations and some AS2.

After every change, I test it with "ctrl + enter". Everything was working fine, until Flash started to export only one version. I've made changes after that - changed images, changed AS2 to do something else, but the export was always one perticullar old version?! I even deleted the whole content of the file (the timeline), then "ctrl + enter" and again it exported the old version, instead of empty white screen.

Tried deleting the swf file, renaming the file, saving it as an older version, restarted the Flash, the computer. Nothing worked. Every time, no matter what I change, it export the same old version of the file. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having similar problems ( [Flash AS3, import old version of class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31644814/flash-as3-import-old-version-of-class) ).

My "shots in the dark":

- do a Save-As from within Flash.  In old versions (7ish), this would cause it to re-organize the Library efficiently for the new file.  I had to do this whenever I deleted/updated audio/video from/in the Library, because it wouldn't free up space in the .fla, leading to huge .fla files as a project went on.
- Check for compiler errors.  This would have jumped out at you, so I doubt this is it.
- Move the .fla to a new directory.  Maybe that will confuse it into resetting whatever is wrong.