# Flash AS3, import old version of class

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cc

I am writing an .as file with a class in it, and using `import` to make it available in my .fla's code.

At first it worked fine.  An in some of my .fla files, it still works fine.

But, one of my files is using an old version of the class, and ignoring any changes I make.

I've tried commenting out the `import` of the class, to see if I'd get a compiler error, but it doesn't give me an error.  It still instantiates the old version of the class.

I've tried `Clear Publish Cache`, but it again still uses the old version of the class.

I've double checked that the class is not defined anywhere in the .fla file.

Comment: Have you tried saving a new copy of the .fla by using the File > Save as... menu item?

Comment: Yup, I did try that.
Finally realized that it was a different folder all-together.  My "move" was just a "copy" and Flash opened the old location, which makes sense.
I wish there was a way to retract a question.

Comment: I'm remembering the old days (version 7ish) when doing a Save As was the only way to make the .fla file forget old video/audio Library assets that had been deleted.  I'd have to do a Save As every so often to bring the .fla file size down.

Comment: The first loaded definition of one given class is the one that will be used throughout the application even if you load new swf with a different definition of that class. The problem is your workflow as a whole. Instead of creating and using a bunch of same class definition all over the place put it in a swc and only use that swc with all your flas.

Comment: You can delete your question if you feel it is just a clerical type error that won't be helpful to future visitors. (eg using the wrong path)  - or , if you think it will be helpful to others, answer your own question.

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis I don't have a delete button.  Is it hidden, or do I need a certain amount of Reputation points?  While the source of my question was just a blunder on my part, I do like some of the things I learned from the responses.

Answer (score 0):

Blunder on my part.  I thought I had "moved" my files, but I had just "copied".

Maybe (best case pride-wise) I used the recent files list, and picked the wrong one.

I like some of the answers I got in the comments though.  Also, I can't find a delete button.